# Displaying multiple validations for FluentUI TextField component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, textfield, fluentui-react

[Example Validations Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfjo5.png)

So I'm converting an old Knockout blade to react, and I need to add multiple validations to a  FluentUI TextField component. The example picture is what these validations should look like, but as of now, I have not been able to find an example of someone doing something similar with this component. I attached what I am currently using for the name field as that only requires one validation, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still relatively new to React/TypeScript so please bear that in mind.

```js
const nameValidation = new RegExp("^$|^[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9]{4,48}[A-Za-z0-9]$");

const validateAndGetError = (value:string): string =>  {
    return nameValidation.test(value) ? "" : ClientResources.Error.Message.validationEntityNameInvalid;
}
// the textfield is receiving the validate through onGetErrorMessage

<TextField styles={fieldStyles} placeholder={props.nameFieldPlaceholder} onGetErrorMessage={validateAndGetError} validateOnFocusOut onChange={(_, n) => setName(n)} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside FluentUI Documentation you have an example for solution you are looking for. Focus is on section [TextField error message variations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui/#/controls/web/textfield):

```js
// Custom validation:
const validation = (value: string) => {
  const x = 'Value must be Marko'
  const y = 'Put five characters'
  const errors = []
  if (value !== 'Marko' && value.length !== 5) {
    errors.push(x, y)
  } else if (value !== 'Marko' && value.length === 5) {
    errors.push(x)
  } else if (value === 'Marko' && value.length !== 5) {
    errors.push(y)
  } 
  return errors;
}

// Render list of errors:
const getValidationErrors = (value: string) => 
<Stack>
  {validation(value).map((x, i) =>
    <Stack key={i} verticalAlign="center" horizontal tokens={richErrorStackTokens}>
      <Icon iconName="Error" styles={richErrorIconStyles} />
      <Text variant="smallPlus">{x}</Text>
    </Stack>)}
</Stack>

<TextField
  label="Your name"
  defaultValue=""
  onGetErrorMessage={getValidationErrors}
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/BarWMaV?editors=0011) working example.

Comment: This is actually quite similar to the solution I was able to come to through a colleague's help. Not sure how I missed this, but thank you for sharing!